# How to click link in Mechanize and Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize to scrape Google Wallet for Order data. I am capturing all the data from the first page, however, I need to automatically link to subsequent pages to get more info.

The #purchaseOrderPager-pagerNextButton will move to the next page so I can pick up more records to capture. The element looks like this. I need to click on it to keep going.

```
<a id="purchaseOrderPager-pagerNextButton" class="kd-button small right"
 href="purchaseorderlist?startTime=0&amp;...
;currentPageStart=1&amp;currentPageEnd=25&amp;inputFullText=">
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/mc3/purchaseorder/page-right.png"></a>
```

However, when I try the following I get an error:

```
  next_page = @orders_page.search("#purchaseOrderPager-pagerNextButton")
  next_page.click
```

The error:

```
undefined method `click' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0x007f9019095550> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`click`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html#method-i-click) is a method of [`Mechanize` class](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html).

Try following form.

```
next_page = @orders_page.at("#purchaseOrderPager-pagerNextButton")
mechanize_instance.click(next_page)
```

**NOTE** Replace `mechanize_instance` with actual variable.

Answer (score 4):

Your one doesn't work, as [`#search`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-search) gives `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` instance. *NodeSet* is a collection of nodes. But in your case it is `next_page` is a *NodeSet* collection, which holds only one element. And [`first`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-first) will give you the [`Nokogiri::XML::Node`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html), which is also an [`Nokogiri::XML::Element`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Element.html).

Write as below :

```
next_page = @orders_page.search("#purchaseOrderPager-pagerNextButton").first
```

Or better to use [`#at`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-at) method.

```
next_page = @orders_page.at("#purchaseOrderPager-pagerNextButton")
```

Now [`#click`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page/Link.html#method-i-click) is a method of [`Mechanize::Page::Link`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page/Link.html#method-i-click) instance. Open the source :

```
# File lib/mechanize/page/link.rb, line 29
def click
  @mech.click self
end
```

Here is the full code :-

```
next_page = @orders_page.at("#purchaseOrderPager-pagerNextButton")
# mech is your Mechanize object.
next_link = Mechanize::Page::Link.new( next_page, mech, @orders_page )
next_link.click
```

[`Mechanize#click`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html#method-i-click) lets you supply a string with the text of the *anchor*/ *button* to click on and `Nokogiri::XML::Node` as well. So we can do :

```
mech.click next_page
```

Let's see why the above code would work :

[*source code lines*](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/lib/mechanize.rb#L359-L363)

```
  referer = current_page()
  href = link.respond_to?(:href) ? link.href :
    (link['href'] || link['src'])
  get href, [], referer
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried your second option (.at) and got: undefined method `click' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x007fd1624e8578> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Also, the .search("...").first option also gives the same error message. I must be missing something else in my attempt.