# How to simulate click in span using Mechanize Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have a webpage with list of pages:

```
<div class="pager">    
  <span class="current_page">1</span>
  <span class="page" samo:page="2">2</span>
  <span class="page" samo:page="3">3</span>
  <span class="page" samo:page="4">4</span>
  <span class="page" samo:page="5">5</span>
  <span class="page" samo:page="6">6</span>
  <span class="page" samo:page="7">7</span>
  <span class="page" samo:page="8">8</span>
  <span class="page" samo:page="9">9</span>
  <span class="page" samo:page="10">10</span>
  <span class="page" samo:page="11">11</span>
</div>
```

How can I click on the span using mechanize?

Comment: You can't. If you're convinced you need to click on `span`s, then you should be using `Watir`

Comment: @pguardiario nope, it's not true, I'll found how to click on span using mechanize

Comment: No, you really won't.

Comment: @pguardiario yes, your right, I can't, did you know how to copy a base64 of image or how to save image without using more then 1 request using Watir?

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like a separate question.

Comment: @pguardiario never mind, I have already found answer for my question:)

Comment: ok, feel free to post it here or otherwise please delete this question.

Comment: @pguardiario it's need to 1 more gem and seems like: 
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir-get-image-content'
 
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'http:example.com'
browser.image(:index, '1').to_png_base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this ASCIIcasts you can perform searches and findings:

> There are two methods on the page object that we can use to extract
>   elements from a page using Nokogiri. The first of these is called at
>   and will return a single element that matches a selector.
>
> ```
> agent.page.at(".edit_item")
> ```
>
> The second method is search. This is similar, but returns an array of
>   all of the elements that match.
>
> ```
> agent.page.search(".edit_item")
> ```

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize

So doing something like:

```
agent.page.at(".page")
```

Will return the array of spans. And then you will be able to work with them and just do the #click action.

EDITED:

As long as the span is a non interactive element, and click is a Link action, you will have to find a workaround:

[How to click link in Mechanize and Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008133/how-to-click-link-in-mechanize-and-nokogiri)

Comment: This: page2 = agent.page.at('.page') is return:
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0xe06ab4 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0xdfbba0 name="class" value="page">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0xdfbb8c name="data-page" value="2">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0xdfb3d0 "2">]>
But when I try to result = page2.click - it doesn't work..

Comment: That's probably because mechanize doesn't support clicking on non interactive items. Span is a flat text in html.

Comment: Editer answer with a new link with more info about this second problem.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I found an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008133/how-to-click-link-in-mechanize-and-nokogiri